# Rails: auto increment counter, scoped to a distant associated element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, counter

I have the following models:

```
Project
  has_many :requirements

Requirement
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :issues

Issue
  belongs_to :requirement
```

I need to have a counter on `Issue` that's scoped to the associated `Project`. Because `Issue` isn't associated directly to `Project` though, but only over the "bridge" of a `Requirement`, I can't simply use a gem like [auto_increment](https://github.com/felipediesel/auto_increment).

So how should I do this? I see the following ways.

**Idea 1: using an after_validation_on_create**

```
class Issue
  after_validation_on_create :increment_counter, if: -> { errors.empty? }

  private
  def increment_counter
    if requirement
      if requirement.project
        self.counter = ... # Count all the findings + 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This feels ugly to me though, as we have to make sure there's an associated requirement and project. Maybe there's a more beautiful way using an SQL query that fails gracefully if the associated objects are missing?

Update: I found the following to work: `Project.joins(:findings).where(id: id).count`. I'm not sure how Rails does this though (it automatically joins `requirements`).

**Idea 2: associating finding to project**

I could simply associate the the finding to the project, too:

```
Project
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :findings # New!

Requirement
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :issues

Issue
  belongs_to :requirement
  belongs_to :project # New!
```

This way I could use the auto_increment gem easily. But it feels a little redundant, as an issue already belongs to a project through the requirement in between. So the `project_id`s of both the issue and the requirement **always need to have the same value**, otherwise my data is corrupted, so I would have to make this sure somehow (but how?).

Both ideas don't feel "clean", they don't look "rails style" to me. There must be a better way! Any idea?

Comment: This should be possible on `Project` model: `has_many :issues, through: :requirements` and on `Issue` model you can do `delegate :project, to: :requirement, allow_nil: true`. So would this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out about `has_many/has_one through`, so it works the following way now:

```
Project
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :findings, through: :requirements

Requirement
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :issues

Issue
  belongs_to :requirement
  has_one :project, through: :requirement
```

Now I do the following:

```
class Finding < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :increment_consecutive_number

  private

  def increment_consecutive_number
    self.consecutive_number = project.findings.count + 1 if project
  end
end
```